# New Photography Blog @ BlogOverflow.com!

Tags: discussion, blog

Its finally here, after all the *mild teasing* and *bated breath*, Photography @ StackExchange now has a blog at photo.blogoverflow.com.

**(In fact, thanks to @ElendilTheTall for the first post!  Check it out!)**

While it is currently in its beta phase, this new blog will allow our community to expand and grow and bring to our members new and useful content in ways that we truly feel are necessary, but which have been largely impossible given the fundamental premise of the StackExchange Q&A sites. Soon community contributors will begin publishing articles covering topics such as photographic techniques, post processing tips and tricks, do-it-yourself and on-the-cheap home equipment projects, showcases of underviewed and undervalued questions and answers, and hopefully much, much more!

So, head on over to [photo.blogoverflow.com](http://photo.blogoverflow.com) and start reading! If you wish to become a contributor, join our chat room, [Photographic Memories](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photographic-memories), and chat with myself or @rfusca about what you would like to contribute, and we'll find a place for you.

We'd love to have a variety of contributors, so don't hesitate to offer up your writing skills and knowledge.  The barrier for becoming a contributor will be low but we'll be approving all posts before they're publicly available.

Comment: This is great news !

Comment: Whoa! good news! :D

Comment: It looks good! Nice article to start too.

Comment: To add my $0.02, I think this is super cool and I look forward to reading folks' posts!

Comment: @Reid - would you be interested in contributing anything?  We'd *love* some more contributors.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to bring some good news.

We're shooting to increase the visibility of the blog. As such, now **the blog links on your site footer and header point to the actual Photography blog, rather than just the normal Stack Exchange blog**! It will also be highlighted with a bright red notice for 24 hours after every new post, to help people realize there's cool new articles to read.

I also encourage people to use your [Community Ads](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011) to help promote your blog. If you create a simple advert for your blog and it accumulates enough votes, you'll end up with a handy link to your blog that'll be right in your standard advertisement cycle. It's a very handy avenue and I recommend looking into it.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, thats already increased considerable site traffic today.  I'm trying to work on a community ad to put up, but real work keeps getting in the way.

Comment: Thank you very much, Grace! I've been sucked into the black hole that is work lately, and have not had the chance to dedicate time to our new blog like I had hoped. Hopefully this will help build some traffic, and maybe we can get some new contributors out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay. Elendil's post has finally been submitted, complete with gear photos and sample shots.

Comment: What do I do if I want to submit an article? Also submitted comments doesn't show any confirmation message after submission. I don't know whether my comment was posted or not :(

Comment: @ShutterBug - for some reason, your comment got flag as spam, fixed now

Comment: @ShutterBug regarding submitting an article, just drop by chat and let jrista or I know and we'll set you up with a contributor account.  You'll write the article, we edit, advise, etc and then published.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay on new blog posts - we're still getting it sorted out.  I'll go ahead and announce the new one here for now.

We just got another post up - a rainy day project for when you just can't get out to shoot!  Thanks again to Elendil!

Next week I'll be publishing an interview with Matt Grum!

Answer (score 0):

Another blog post is up, this time an interview with top rep user and virtual superhero, Matt Grum.