# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Very little mileage was gotten out of our previous thread. Let's begin the new year with a fresh start and renewed interest, neh?

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools and resources for the avid photographer
- techniques or tutorials for picture perfection
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1823).

Comment: Good deal, we really need to make better use of this feature.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 5):

[image: We'll help you learn about Photography]

Comment: Not necessarily *this* answer, but should we use this feature to show off some of our best questions (why RAW, exposure triangle/rectangle, etc.)?  Photo is @matt-grum's from http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5993/how-do-you-photograph-christmas-lights which is why it won't show up if you follow that link.

Comment: It is an exposure _tricycle_ :)

Comment: That tricycle would make a *great* 220x250 banner... hint hint....