# Is it possible to reduce the header size due to the large picture of the day?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often browse the site on my MacBook Air and various iOS devices and the header takes away substantially from the content. Can I disable the very tall (by stack exchange standards) header so that I can get more of the content?

I don't want to force everyone to forego the fun of seeing an image larger than could be hosted as a [community ad placement](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/community-promotion-ads-2013) or otherwise hosted in the sidebar, but the usability of the site is not optimal for smallish screens that are wider than they are tall. (And on meta where there is no image - the design really falls flat in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

It *is* disabled on the mobile version of the site. You can turn that on with the "mobile" link in the site footer.

Comment: I'll give that view a shot on my Mac. It's been a while since I've tried that codebase on computer.

Comment: It kind of fails if your browser window is wide; it's really not meant for that. But it's pretty good on phones and tablets.

Comment: It does look pretty awkward landscape mode to me. In portrait mode, I don't mind the header so much since I get more "content" and less header percentage wise. +1 for the mobile/full preferences using site specific cookies so I can keep the normal view for my other sites on SE.